# how to get id passed from other page in React?

Tags: reactjs, frontend, mern

I'm trying to get all composers data from backend, and click one of the composer, a profile page will be opened. Now I have all the composers in 'composer page', but I can't get profile page if I click one of the composer.
this is the composer page, below snippet is one single composer, when I click, it should jump to the composer's profile page.

```
    {albums.map(album => (
                    <Link
                        to={{
                            pathname: `/api/composers/${album._id}`,
                            search: `?id=${album._id}`
                        }}
                        key={album._id}
                        style={{ textDecoration: "none", color: "black" }}
                    >
                        <Card className="albums-card">
                            <img
                                // src={"https://via.placeholder.com/168x118.png"}
                                src={album.image}
                                alt={`data thumbnail`}
                            />
                            <h5>Composer {album.name}</h5>
                            <h6>Composer {album.nationality}</h6>
                        </Card>
                    </Link>
                ))
```

below is the profile page

```
     let id = new URLSearchParams(search).get('backUrl')
    useEffect(() => {
        setIsLoading(true);
        const fetchData = async () => {
            const result = await fetch(
                `http://localhost:3000/api/composers/id`
            );
            const resultJson = await result.json();
            setItems(resultJson);
            setIsLoading(false);
        };
        fetchData();
    }, [itemFound, _id]);
```

I don't know how to get the id from composer page, the error is as below

```
    Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Failed to fetch
fetchData
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Innovation_project/client/src/components/pages/Composer/Profile.js:22
  19 | useEffect(() => {
  20 |     setIsLoading(true);
  21 |     const fetchData = async () => {
> 22 |         const result = await fetch(
     | ^  23 |             `http://localhost:3000/api/composers/b`
  24 |         );
  25 |         const resultJson = await result.json();
View compiled
(anonymous function)
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Innovation_project/client/src/components/pages/Composer/Profile.js:29
  26 |            setItems(resultJson);
  27 |            setIsLoading(false);
  28 |        };
> 29 |        fetchData();
     | ^  30 |    }, [itemFound, _id]);
  31 | 
  32 |    const onItemHandler = (value, index) => {
View compiled
▶ 12 stack frames were collapsed.
```

The router is as below:

```
 <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/api/composers" element={<Composer />} />
          <Route path="/api/composers/:id" element={<ComposerMongodb />} />
      </Routes>
```

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance

Comment: you can check [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params) hook ...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help you debug.

1. Are you getting the right id (please confirm by console log the id) . You can use useParams hook to read id from the url.
   https://reactrouter.com/en/main/hooks/use-params
2. Also check the url you are hitting is correct. (you can check in the networks tab in the browser) or log it first instead of directly passing it in fetch.

I think you are passing string 'id' instead of actual value ${id} inside backticks.
const result = await fetch(
`http://localhost:3000/api/composers/${id}`
);
Hope this helps!!